# Python: Append item to list N times

Tags: python, list

This seems like something Python would have a shortcut for. I want to append an item to a list N times, effectively doing this:

```
l = []
x = 0
for i in range(100):
    l.append(x)
```

It would seem to me that there should be an "optimized" method for that, something like:

```
l.append_multiple(x, 100)
```

Is there?

---

<sub>If you want to append elements *from another sequence* (instead of the same value repeatedly, you can just `.extend` with that sequence directly. See [How to append to the end of an empty list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339235).</sub>

Comment: Ended up going with `l.extend([x] * 100)` since it fit my situation best. Amber gets the answer credit for being the most comprehensive. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you understand Python's reference semantics before using this for anything non-trivial. The x's appended to l are all the same x, so mutating one of them affects them all (all one of them, referred to 100 times).

Comment: For clarification: I am using it for integers, so my usage is safe.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

For immutable data types:

```
l = [0] * 100
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

l = ['foo'] * 100
# ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', ...]
```

For values that are stored by reference and you may wish to modify later (like sub-lists, or dicts):

```
l = [{} for x in range(100)]
```

(The reason why the first method is only a good idea for constant values, like ints or strings, is because only a shallow copy is does when using the `<list>*<number>` syntax, and thus if you did something like `[{}]*100`, you'd end up with 100 references to the same dictionary - so changing one of them would change them all. Since ints and strings are immutable, this isn't a problem for them.)

If you want to add to an existing list, you can use the `extend()` method of that list (in conjunction with the generation of a list of things to add via the above techniques):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
a.extend(b)
# a is now [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Or combine both suggestions into the form of `a.extend(b*n)` where `n` is the times you want to repeat elements in b

Answer (score 41):

Use extend to add a list comprehension to the end.

```
l.extend([x for i in range(100)])
```

See the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more information.

Comment: Or get rid of the loop: `l.extend([x] * 100)`

Answer (score 13):

Itertools repeat combined with list extend.

```
from itertools import repeat
l = []
l.extend(repeat(x, 100))
```

Answer (score 11):

I had to go another route for an assignment but this is what I ended up with.

```
my_array += ([x] * repeated_times)
```

Comment: this is so ridiculously simple compared to the other ones, i love it

Answer (score 7):

```
l = []
x = 0
l.extend([x]*100)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a list comprehension

```
l = [x for i in range(10)];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add any value like this for several times:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
#if you want to add on item 3 times for example:
for i in range(len(a)):
    j = 3
    while j != 0:
        b.append(a[i])
        j-=1
#now b = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```