# Why does "x = x.append(...)" not work in a for loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to append objects to the end of a list repeatedly, like so:

```
list1 = []
n = 3
for i in range(0, n):
    list1 = list1.append([i])
```

But I get an error like: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`. Is this because list1 starts off as an empty list? How do I fix this error?

Comment: No -1 please. The fact that append() returns None can trick beginers. The question is genuine.

Comment: Rather than using a loop to `.append` each time, it is simpler and more efficient to just `.extend` with all the values: `list1.extend(range(n))` - no loop needed. However, the question isn't really about the loop, that was just what turned the problem of returning `None` into an actual exception. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605 (only tangentially related).

Comment: I didn't mark this as a duplicate because the underlying task - repeatedly appending to a list - merits consideration on its own. However, most questions about `.append` will be better closed as a duplicate of the other canonical.

Comment: There are better identified canonicals now (part of the material is covered by something I ended up having to write myself), so this is closed now. There are two separate issues here, which makes it not properly focused as a canonical: the debugging issue of `.append` in a loop (which is a special case of `.append` returning None), and the how-to of building a list iteratively.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`append` actually *changes* the list. Also, it takes an **item**, not a list. Hence, all you need is

```
for i in range(n):
   list1.append(i)
```

(By the way, note that you can use `range(n)`, in this case.)

I assume your actual use is more complicated, but you may be able to use a list comprehension, which is more pythonic for this:

```
list1 = [i for i in range(n)]
```

Or, in this case, in Python 2.x `range(n)` in fact creates the list that you want already, although in Python 3.x, you need `list(range(n))`.

Comment: thanks that last bit was very helpful and shortened my code by a bunch

Comment: @AndrewJaffe, what about a list of lists?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. `append` adds to the outermost list, but you can append to a nested list by indexing it: `a[-1].append(3)` appends `3` to the last sublist of `a`.

Answer (score 20):

You don't need the assignment operator.  append returns None.

Answer (score 6):

`append` returns None, so at the second iteration you are calling method `append` of NoneType. Just remove the assignment:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    list1.append([i])
```

Answer (score 3):

Mikola has the right answer but a little more explanation.  It will run the first time, but because append returns `None`, after the first iteration of the for loop, your assignment will cause `list1` to equal `None` and therefore the error is thrown on the second iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer the `+` operator than `append`:

```
for i in range(0, n):

    list1 += [[i]]
```

But this is creating a new list every time, so might not be the best if performance is critical.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you also can use insert in order to put number into the required position within list:

```
initList = [1,2,3,4,5]
initList.insert(2, 10) # insert(pos, val) => initList = [1,2,10,3,4,5]
```

And also note that in python you can always get a list length using method len()

Answer (score 0):

Like Mikola said, `append()` returns a void, so every iteration you're setting list1 to a nonetype because append is returning a nonetype.  On the next iteration, list1 is null so you're trying to call the append method of a null.  Nulls don't have methods, hence your error.

Answer (score -3):

use my_list.append(...)
and do not use and other list to append as list are mutable.

Comment: This answer is hard to understand (I'm not sure what you mean by the second part, for example) and either repeats information from the existing answers (from 2014) or (if taken literally) is flat out wrong (OP's code contains no `my_list` variable).