# Why doesn't my script display the newly created file?

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that opens a file and for each test case, it should write the total number of items gathered in that case and display the total amount $ that it costs.

When running my code:

```
f = open("shopping.txt", "r")
outFile = open("results.txt", "w")
t = int(f.readline().strip())
for z in range(t):
    # Assuming prices are unique
    myList = {}
    items = int(f.readline().strip())
    ind = 1
    # Read each line for each item
    for i in range(items):
        p, w = map(int, f.readline().strip().split())
        myList[p] = [w, ind]
        ind+=1
    weights = []
    F = int(f.readline().strip())
    for i in range(F):
        weights.append(int(f.readline().strip()))
        RES = []
        values = []
    for weight in weights:
        sortedPrice = sorted(myList.keys())[::-1]
        m = 0
        p = 0
        tmp = []

        # Grabbing all possible results using greedy method
        # Max price stored into values array and item # in RES array.
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        R = []
        s = 0
        p = 0
        if myList[sortedPrice[i]][0]<=weight:
            s=myList[sortedPrice[i]][0]
            p=sortedPrice[i]
            R+=myList[sortedPrice[i]][1],
    for j in range(i+1, len(myList)):
        if myList[sortedPrice[j]][0]+s<=weight:
            s+=myList[sortedPrice[j]][0]
            p+=sortedPrice[j]
            R+=myList[sortedPrice[j]][1],
        if m<p:
            m = p
            tmp = R
            tmp.sort()
            RES.append(tmp)
            values.append(m)
    outFile.write("Test Case %d\n" %(z+1))
    outFile.write("Total Price: %d\n" %(sum(values)))
    outFile.write("Member Items:\n")
    for i in range(len(RES)):
        outFile.write("%d: %s" %(i+1, " ".join(map(str, RES[i]))))
        f.close()
        outFile.close()
```

I get the result:

```
Test Case 1
Total Price: 0
Member Items:
Test Case 2
Total Price: 0
Member Items:
```

When I expected something like this:

```
Test Case1
Total Price 72
Member Items
1: 1
Test Case2
Total Price 568
Member Items
1: 3 4
2: 3 6
3: 3 6 
4: 3 4 6
```

I am relatively new to programming in general so if there is any insight anyone could give for my code, I would appreciate it. Adding to this, my guess is that the `sum()` and/or the `map` commands may be breaking and not working as intended, as I'm writing to the file to get the total value and items of the case.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I tried this on the "values" and "RES" array, and it resulted in the same output to the file.

Comment: @JuanEstevez: the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=append) disagrees with you. [Actually running your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339235/how-to-append-to-the-end-of-an-empty-list/6339248#6339248) does too.

Comment: You are closing the files while still (deeply) inside loops. Only do that at the very end. (Or, even better, use a more idiomatic and safer [`open with`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) construct.)

Comment: Voting to close because there is no [mre] here.