# How, in a loop, can I append incrementally increasing numbers of zeros to the end of a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a loop that will append an increasing number (one, then two, then three, etc.) of zeros to the end of a list with each iteration. Thus the list's length should be 1, then 3, then 6, then 10, etc. (Each of these list items in turn will then have 1 added to it by a nested loop as long as the loop's conditional holds true, so the list will not stay a list of only zeroes for the loop's duration).

Here is my attempt:

```
def myfunction(limit: int):
    integerlist = []
    newzeroes = 0
    increment_index = 0
    while sum(integerlist) < limit: 
        newzeroes += 1
        integerlist.extend([0]*newzeroes)
        while sum(integerlist) < limit:
            integerlist[increment_index % len(integerlist)] += 1
            increment_index += 1
    return integerlist
```

I expected this to return lists with lengths such as 1, 3, 6, 10, or etc., but instead it always returns a list with length of 1 regardless of the input value. Since

```
integerlist.extend([0]*newzeroes)
```

wasn't adding zeroes to the list, I also tried

```
integerlist = integerlist + [[0]*newzeroes]
```

but this throws the error "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'".

I am a complete beginner to coding. I suspect this might be a basic syntax problem, but I have not been able to pinpoint what my mistake might be (relevant posts such as "[Python: append item to list N times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59226917/17526812)" seem to suggest using the same kind of methods and  syntax I'm trying to use).

Comment: this `integerlist = integerlist + [[0]*newzeroes]` throws the other error because `integerlist` become a list of lists, then in the line `integerlist[increment_index % len(integerlist)] += 1` you try to add 1 to that list of lists.

Comment: @Mauxricio Thank you for pointing that out. I changed it to ```integerlist = integerlist + ([0]*newzeros)``` to make it add the zeroes as list items rather than adding another list into ```integerlist```. This stops it from throwing the error, but I am still trying to figure out why it does not add zeroes to ```integerlist```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the second `while` loop isn't needed, as it will always be `True` if the first `while` loop is `True`.  So you can remove it, along with one of the variables.  Also, I suspect `increment_index % len(integerlist)` should equal `increment_value` the way your code is structured, in that case it's also not needed.

```
def myfunction(limit: int):
    integerlist = []
    increment_index = 0
    while sum(integerlist) < limit: 
        increment_index += 1
        integerlist.extend([0]*increment_index)
        integerlist[increment_index-1] += 1
    return integerlist

print(myfunction(3))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Following from the description of the output in the comment;

```
def myfunction(limit: int):
    integerlist = []
    increment = 1
    while True:
        integerlist.extend([0] * increment)
        for i in range(len(integerlist)):
            integerlist[i] += 1
            if sum(integerlist) >= limit:
                return integerlist
        increment += 1
```

Comment: I want ```myfunction(3)``` to output ```[2, 1, 0]``` (in the first iteration a zero would be appended to the empty list and then 1 added to that zero; in the second iteration two more zeros would be appended to the list, and 1 would be added the first and second list integers, at which point the conditional would be False, so nothing would be added to the third list integer. I should have clarified that the addition of 1 to each integer in the list needs to happen *one by one* for the full list in every iteration, and stop as soon as the conditional is False, even partway through the list.

Comment: OK, let me add to my answer